# Google Recaptcha javascript loading multiple times

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I'm including the Google Recaptcha on my website in the following way;

In the header section;

```
<script async src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=fr'></script>
```

And in the body section (I've removed my key for the sake of the example);

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="*"></div>
```

Yet when the page loads, the Google Chrome console shows the following;

[image: Google Chrome Console]

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on? Why is seemingly the same 69.0kb file being loaded 3 times?

Comment: I've got it on my site and it's exactly the same situation. Must be a quirk or maybe even bug in one of the the google scripts, I guess. Don't think it's anything you've done wrong (unless we both have)

Comment: I skimmed through the recaptcha code, it does it itself. It does a request to /api/anchor and requests for a /api/webworker.js

Comment: In this case, is it exactly the same file being loaded 3 times, or is it loading two other files after the original recaptcha file? I've been considering doing an ajax call to load recaptcha as it seems to leave a pretty significant footprint on load even with the asynchronized attribute.

Comment: Why are you using `async`?

Comment: Best guess is that they are API calls necessary to how recaptcha operates. Second seems to be just a request, the third returns a file. If you are worried about page load, you can create a script that only loads the recaptcha once you need it: eg, when the user clicks a form field

Comment: I'm using async because recaptcha isn't necessary to viewing the page, also because google pagespeed insights complains about it and lowers the score.

Comment: Are you found the solution?
I have the same problem

Answer (score 8):

Answering for anybody who comes across this later.

This is addressed in a GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/issues/335). Recaptcha runs across multiple frames, so it's loaded multiple times since each frame needs access to the script. This is intended behaviour, apparently.

Comment: I am getting bad Lighthouse scores because of this. It is loaded 3 times in my case with 1 include.

Comment: is there anyway to stop it from behaving this way?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation. reCAPTCHA loaded 3 times, however checking my competitor's site with Pagespeed Insights, I could see theirs only loaded once.

Did some (frustrated) digging into my plugins, deactivated and reactivated some while running pagespeed insights after each change. I wish I had taken screenshots to prove the change, but indeed it went from 3 to 2, to 1.

Basically I had discovered there were 3 different plugins running reCAPTCHA. Problem is solved finally. Finding the excessive ones is the tricky part. Mine were within the plugins CF7 and Gravity Forms.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer refers to plugins, presumably in some kind of CMS. You could make it more helpful if you included additional information about your setup and CMS, such as the names of the relevant products you are using. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Cadence yes, *but* at least he provides some insight into how to manage this frustrating situation. Thank you